# How to stop the process started from python gui?

Tags: python, user-interface, module, process, pysimplegui

I created a simple gui tool in python which has a button which starts some process by calling my python module in background.

I want to stop the process if a condition not satisfied and want to popup an error msg.

I am not able to find a way to stop the process once it is started from button. How can i do this without closing the GUI?

**For info** : I am using PysimpleGUI to create gui.

Comment: Code is badly needed in your example. There are many ways to "start a process" in Python, some have nothing to do with processes at all but rather Threads.

If you're running as a Thread, then you can't "stop" the thread.  But, you can send the thread a message or more simplistically, use a variable that is periodically checked by the Thread.

Comment: If you are using threads, this article https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-different-ways-to-kill-a-thread/ talks about several ways of "killing" them including the ones I mentioned above.  There are some interesting techniques in there that I was not aware of.